# From a Set of Booleans, how to return Tuple containing number that are true, number that are false?

Tags: scala, set

I'm pretty new of Scala, and I know there must be a nice way to do this, but I can't come up with something nice and readable.

I have a set of ids (strings), and for each id, I run some function that returns a boolean.

The result is a Set[Boolean], but I want to create a tuple containing two numbers, one is the number of true and one is the number of false.

What's a clean/readable way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your `ids` and `f`:

```
val ids: Set[String] = ???
def f(s: String): Boolean = ???
```

The following gets you there fairly concisely using the built-in `partition` function:

```
val (trues, falses) = ids partition f
(trues.size, falses.size)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the `count` method of a `Seq`:

```
val ids: Seq[String] = Seq("1", "12", "3")

def containsOne(s: String) = s.contains('1')
val processedIds = ids.map(containsOne)

// first item is amount of trues, second is amount of falses
val count: (Int, Int) =  (processedIds.count(identity),  processedIds.count(_ == false))
```

You must use a `Seq` as a `Set` will 'flatten' out the collection of `Boolean` (to a maximum size of 2, no duplicates allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Given your fn,

```
scala> def fn(x: String) = x.contains("customer")
fn: (x: String)Boolean
```

you have to `.map` to create `boolean -> Set(Id)`, then aggregate by boolean, then count how many IDs for each boolean

```
scala> Set("customerId-1", "customerId-2", "id-3", "id-4")
          .map(x => fn(x) -> x)
          .groupBy(_._1)
          .map { case (boolean, set) => boolean -> set.size }
res51: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Boolean,Int] = Map(false -> 2, true -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expression that counts the number of even elements and odd elements in the set:

```
Set(3,4,5,6,8,3).toSeq.map{_ % 2 == 0}
    .foldLeft((0,0)){(t,c) => if (c) (t._1+1, t._2) else (t._1, t._2+1)}
```

The `toSeq` is necessary to keep the output of `map` from being just a `Set`.

Just replace `{_ % 2 == 0}` with a call to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a one-liner (except that it doesn't fit on one line in this little box:(

My test function is true if division by 3 leaves a remainder of 1, and false otherwise, and I'm running it on the range 1 to 6 (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5):

```
scala> val x = (1 to 6).partition(_%3 == 1) match
     | { case (s1,s2) => (s1.length, s2.length) }
x: (Int, Int) = (2,4)
```

And so, writing the main function in a little more generality,

```
scala> def boolCounter[T](
   | s: Seq[T],
   | f: T => Boolean): (Integer, Integer) = 
   | s.partition(f) match { case (s1, s2) => (s1.length, s2.length) }
boolCounter: [T](s: Seq[T], f: T => Boolean)(Integer, Integer)

scala> val r = 1 to 6
r: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 6

scala> val f: Int => Boolean = { x => x%3 == 1}
f: Int => Boolean = $$Lambda$1252/1891031939@5a090f62

scala> boolCounter(r, f)
res0: (Integer, Integer) = (2,4)
```